# Need to Show 2 pages forward and back in middle pages of ngx-pagination

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, shared-libraries, ngx-pagination

I am unable to show 2 pages forward and back with current selected tab. Tried with below code.

```
<div *ngFor="let device of displayDevices | paginate: { itemsPerPage: itemPerPage, currentPage: selectedPage };"></div>

<pagination-controls (pageChange)="pageChanged($event)" responsive="false" autoHide="true"></pagination-controls>
```

Comment: Please edit your question with concrete code examples of what you're asking

Comment: @Lonefish : I want to achieve like this screenshot. https://i.stack.imgur.com/3trYV.png

Comment: Edit your question with what you want to achieve and show your current code. As it is now, nobody can help you without seeing your code.

Comment: @Lonefish  edited with code which I am trying

Comment: @Lonefish : anything which m missing now ?? why m not getting any answers ?